# How to apply a function to the a tags in only one specific div or class without jquery

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have several menus on one page and want the link that the user clicks in each menu to change colors and remain that color until the user clicks another link in that menu. I have this code:

**JavaScript**

```
function bookswitchColor(element, color) {
    links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        links.item(i).style.color = 'red';
    element.style.color = "#0E00EB";

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="book" class="book">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:TheMenu()" onclick="bookswitchColor(this) ;">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:book1()" onclick="bookswitchColor(this) ;">Book1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:book2()" onclick="bookswitchColor(this) ;">book2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Which works except that it changes the a tags on the entire page.  This page displays a library of books.  When a user clicks on one of the books, I need that book to remain highlighted(color changed).  Clicking on a book calls a list of chapters for that book which the user clicks to read that chapter.  I need the chapter to remain highlighted(color changed) also without affecting the other menus.

**I would like to avoid jQuery.**

Comment: I don't understand why not to use jQuery: $('.book a').click(function(){ $(this).css('color', '#0E00Eb'); })

Comment: @Justinas this user apparently does not want to use jQuery at all.

Comment: @Pointy i understand that, but sometimes they don't want to use it because they don't know how to.

Comment: @Justinas But sometime, like this case, it is only a performance downgrade to include jQuery for a single purpose. Always ask yourself if [you really need jQuery.](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this line

```
links=document.getElementsByTagName("a") ;
```

with this one:

```
var links = document.getElementById("book").getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getElementsByTagName()` from any element node.

```
  var links = document.getElementById('book').getElementsByTagName('a');
```